# Download file served by ASP.NET Core using AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I have server code on ASP.NET Core which returns a file:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("update")]
    public IActionResult GetUpdate(int progId, string version)
    {
        var update = db.Updates.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ProgramId == progId && u.Version == version);
        if (update != null)
        {
            return new FileContentResult(update.Zip, "file/zip");
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

I need to download it with AJAX somehow.
I tried to do it like this:

```
$('#testBtn').click(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://localhost:44356/api/managment/update',
    data: 'progId=1&version=1.1',
    success: function(data) {
        const datafile = new Uint8Array(new Buffer(data));
        fs.writeFile('test.zip', datafile, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('The file has been saved!');
        });
    }
})
```

And more different combinations with buffers and arrays, but nothing worked.

Can please anyone suggests what should I do, or where am I wrong?

Comment: You mention Node.js, but that's client side code, using `jQuery`. I'm confused.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or exceptions?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande this is electron. As i know electron based on node.js, right?

Comment: @Sean nope. Files are coming up with 0 kb size or, in my situation with zip archives, size doubled and in archive there is 1 broken file

Comment: I think i'm missing something about types, asp.net core webapp forms FileContentResult with parameter update.Zip, which is byte array, but i don't know, what i have on exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researches, found that i can return base64 string from byte array, then write it easily.
Server side (asp.net core 2.2):

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("update")]
    public string GetUpdate(int progId, string version)
    {
        var update = db.Updates.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ProgramId == progId && u.Version == version);
        if (update != null)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(update.Zip);
        }
        return "failed";
    }
```

Client side (electron):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://localhost:44356/api/managment/update?progId=1&version=1.1',
    success: function(data) {
        fs.writeFile('test2.zip', data, {encoding: 'base64'}, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('The file has been saved!');
        });
    }
})
```